# Is there a mysql substitue for Infosystems Cache?

Tags: cache, sql, flatfile

I have an ERP with a flat file "database" written in PL/B.  We use Intersystems Cache to read those flat files into MSQL tables.  The Cache scripts are vendor provided and we have zero direct access to the tables.

Ideally, we want to use an open source analog to Intersystems Cache and see if we can build to match our vendor provided system.

Web searches using the term "cache" are futile as all returns refer to the database cache instead of to the product Cache and it's possible analogs.

Does anyone know of an Intersystems Cache alternative?

Comment: Oops... for every place that I wrote Infosystems, I should have written Intersystems

Comment: I edited your post, but in the future use the edit link below your question to fix any mistakes instead of mentioning them in a comment.

Comment: Do you really mean [MSQL (mini sql)](http://www.hughes.com.au/products/msql/)? Or do you perhaps mean the more common databases [MSSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) or [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Cache scripts are vendor provided and we have zero direct access
>   to the tables.

How's that? Open the Caché-Terminal (or activate and use telnet) and you can access all your globals using [MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS) (or CachéScript, a slightly fancier version). You should be able to store your own routines and work with your data any way you like.

There's at least one other product using MUMPS (=Database and programming environment) which is actively used: [GT.M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GT.M)

Addendum:

> We use Intersystems Cache to read those flat files into MSQL tables.

I think you mean Caché SQL, Caché provides an "SQL-interface" (SQL-92) to store and access data (using JDBC, ODBC etc.). imho thats an odd way to interface with Caché, but most likely your ERP has no other means to do so.

Comment: Trurl, thanks I'll give MUMPS, CacheScript and GT.M a try.

Comment: If you've never seen MUMPS before: Brace yourself. It's... strange. But i kinda like it ;)